# Orientation contour

Tags: complex-analysis, plane-curves

[image]

In my textbook they say the small circle arc has negative orientation. How so? If you travel along the contour the interior of the closed curve is on the left right?

Comment: Positive orientation: Counterclockwise. Negative orientation: Clockwise

Comment: Thank you but the definition that they give in the book is: The positive orientation of a simple closed curve is the one that places the interior region to our left when traced.

Comment: It's equivalent if you think about it

Comment: So clockwise and anti-clockwise senses are same if you think about it?

Comment: I cant see how they are equivalent could you give a hint?

Answer (score 0):

By rotation convention:  CCW rotation positive, CW rotation is negative with respect to the pole desired to be isolated.

Comment: Thank you but the definition that they give in the book is: The positive orientation of a simple closed curve is the one that places the interior region to our left when traced.

Comment: Unfortunate. Right or left placement of a region is meaningless when referring to a pole.